# Save tabulate as csv

Tags: csv, save, stata

I am interested in saving Stata output from `tabulate` (or a similar command) into a CSV file.

For example,

```
sysuse auto, clear
tab headroom rep78
```

I would like to export the results (mainly the body of the table) into a CSV file. How can I do this?

Comment: in Stata `tabulate` is a command, not a function. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sysuse auto, clear

tabout headroom rep78 using tabtest.csv, style(csv)
```

`tabout` is from SSC. That means `ssc install tabout` to install.

Comment: Simpler than I was expecting. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you want to rely on built-in functionalities only you can do:

```
sysuse auto, clear
tab rep78 foreign, matcell(x)
svmat x
list x* in 1/10
export delimited x1 x2 using "test", replace
```

As discussed on the [StataCorp website](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/saving-frequencies-produced-by-tabulate/).